# Cannot set Python path in Aquamacs OSX 10.8

Tags: python, macos, environment-variables

I am using these lines in my Preferences.el

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/bin")
(require 'python-mode)
(setenv "PYTHONPATH" "~/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/bin")
```

But when I do C-c C-c, it is still picking up default Apple Python(2.7.2 instead of 2.7.3 EPD). EPD is running in terminal as default. Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Use this [package](https://github.com/purcell/exec-path-from-shell). And add these lines into Preferences.el

```
(require 'exec-path-from-shell)
(exec-path-from-shell-initialize)
```